# White View on Xcode - It doesn't load labels and images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have some problem with my View in `Xcode`. I have a `view` called `"dettagliCampeggioVC"` and I call it from 2 different views.

Everytime I call it I use the following code:

`[self presentViewController:dettagliCampeggioVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

this is what the simulator shows:

http://imageshack.us/f/843/schermata032456378alle1.png/

and this is what the simulator should show:

http://imageshack.us/f/21/schermata032456378alle1.png/

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**
I just forgot to set NibName as "DettagliCampeggioVC" on IB,

Comment: Other controls are not probably added as expected. Can you please share some more code?

Comment: on file .h I have

#import "DettagliCampeggioVC.h"
DettagliCampeggioVC *objDettagliCampeggio;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DettagliCampeggioVC *objDettagliCampeggio;

and synthesize objDettagliCampeggio

Comment: Did any of these answers help you if not please add your answer and accept it so to help future users. You shouldn't put your answer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

@gabboSonc,
May be you have not instantiated the dettagliCampeggioVC class.

Use as below:

```
ViewController *mvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dettagliCampeggioVC"];
    [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Give "dettagliCampeggioVC" as id in your storyboard for dettagliCampeggioVC class.